# Spring integration XMPP and Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: xmpp, spring-integration, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using the spring integration xmpp module to write a custom implementation of a 3rd party Server connecting to GCM cloud services, as in [GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP)](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html).

So far I've successfully connected to the GCM server, however when I send a message to the server I end up with something like:

```
<message id="m-1366082849205" to="REGISTRATION_ID">
<body>{"hello":"world"}</body>
</message>
```

, but I need to send something like this:

```
  <message id="">
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
  {
      "to":"REGISTRATION_ID",
      "message_id":"m-1366082849205"
      "data":
      {
          "hello":"world",
      }
  }
  </gcm>
</message>
```

I use the latest SI version, 4.0.4, this is my configuration in the xml:

```
<int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="gcmOutboundAdapter" channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"
    xmpp-connection="gcmConnection" auto-startup="true"/>
```

I'm sending messages with the usual MessageBuilder like this:

```
Message<String> xmppOutboundMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(xmppPayload)
        .setHeader(XmppHeaders.TO, REGISTRATION_ID)
        .build();
```

where xmppPayload is a json string.

I need to configure/override the way the xmpp message is composed, what is the best practice to achieve the result? Should I override the class implementing int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter with a custom service activator, is there anyway to configure the way the xmpp message is composed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you have a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854835/what-are-the-right-parameters-for-xmpp-connection-spring-integration-to-make-i) and probably help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">` is a extended content element (see RFC 6120 8.4), which is modelled as PacketExtension in Smack. Do not subclass message, instead create a GCMPacketExtension class and add a instance of it to your message

```
message.addPacketExtension(gcmPackExtension)
```

Comment: See @GaryRussell's answer on how to subclass and configure the message handler to add this extension.

Comment: Thanks @Flow, this solved my issue. I composed the message like this:  Message xmppMessage = new Message();  xmppMessage.addExtension(new GcmPacketExtension(xmppPayload));  and sent it to the outbound adapter.

Comment: That's great! I can't add more `+1`, but would be great, if share what is `GcmPacketExtension`. Does which jar (artifact) contain it?

Comment: @ArtemBilan gcmPacketExtension is the class at the end of this sample [link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#smack) . The behaviour in the link is exactly what I needed, so I just put it in my implementation and called it in the simplest way, because I had to bring up a working server asap in order to enable early testing on the client end.

Comment: Smack now provides a GcmPacketExtension class and provider with https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/commit/e63fe2264729f0d8c975ab4be5a2264e35e89e0b

Answer (score 1):

The format of the message is hard-coded in the Smack `Message.toXML()` method (we use the smack library underneath).

See @Flow's answer.

Then, subclass `ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler`, overriding `handleMessageInternal()` - pretty much copy the code and set the extension after the message is created.

The easiest way to configure your custom handler is probably to put it in a `chain`...

```
<chain input-channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel">
    <bean class="foo.MyChatMessageSendingMessageHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="gcmConnection" />
    </bean>
</chain>
```

Or you can wire it up as a top level bean and inject it into a `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean`.

Feel free to open a [New Feature JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we'll consider adding an extension point to make this a bit easier.

Comment: Never subclass message! `gcm` is a PacketExtension (in Smack terms). See also my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26641368/194894). BTW Smack is no more maintained by Jive software. It's under the open source umbrella of ignite realtime.

Comment: Thanks @Flow - updated my answer to point to yours and retained the code the OP needs in Spring Integration to set that option. We should definitely open up an extension point to allow adding extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked the implementation of ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler and handleMessageInternal will do a simple passthrough of the message if it's of type org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message, so I didn't need to subclass.

Comment: That's true. I reflected it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Until we introduce the `PackExtension` injection, you can overcome it with custom `<transformer ref="">`, because the `<int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter>` can accept `org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message` as a Message `payload`:

```
<transformer ref="toGcmTransformer" output-channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"/>

<int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="gcmOutboundAdapter" channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"
    xmpp-connection="gcmConnection" auto-startup="true"/>
```

---

```
public class ToGcmTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {


   protected Object doTransform(Message<String> message) throws Exception {
        String to = message.getHeaders().get(XmppHeaders.TO, String.class);
        xmppMessage = new org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message(to);
        xmppMessage.setBody(message.getPayload());
        xmppMessage.addPacketExtension(gcmPackExtension);
        return xmppMessage;
   }

}
```

Please, raise an issue about `PackExtension` support.

Answer (score 0):

-->

```
<int:chain input-channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel">
    <!--<int:transformer ref="toGcmTransformer" output-channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"/>-->
    <bean class="com.payumoney.cardhash.service.MyMessageSendingMessageHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="gcmConnection" />
    </bean>
</int:chain>
<int:transformer id="testTransformer" ref="toGcmTransformer" input-channel="gcmInboundNotificationChannel"
         method="doTransform" output-channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"/>
<!--<int:transformer ref="toGcmTransformer" output-channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"/>-->

<int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="gcmOutboundAdapter" channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"
    xmpp-connection="gcmConnection" auto-startup="true"/>

<int:chain input-channel="gcmInboundNotificationChannel">
    <bean class="com.payumoney.cardhash.service.PayumoneyNotificationListeningEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="gcmConnection" />
        <property name="outputChannel" ref="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel" />
    </bean>
</int:chain>

<int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="gcmInboundAdapter"  channel="gcmInboundNotificationChannel" 
    xmpp-connection="gcmConnection" extract-payload="true" auto-startup="true" />
```

Comment: An answer complete with explanation is more likely to be accepted by the OP, and to attract upvotes.