# What are the right parameters for xmpp-connection (spring integration) to make it work with google gcm?

Tags: android, spring, spring-mvc, google-cloud-messaging, spring-integration

I want to setup spring-integration-xmpp on my spring app to make it receive upstream messages from android devices. I can already send messages to the android device using http but I cannot set up the xmpp-connection bean so it gives me:

```
failed to connect to gcm-preprod.googleapis.com; nested exception is Connection failed. No response from server.:
```

This is my spring integration configuration:

```
  <int:channel id="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"/>

  <int-xmpp:xmpp-connection
    id="xmppConnection"
    user="${tracker.server.app.id}@gcm.googleapis.com"
    password="${tracker.auth.key}"
    host="gcm-preprod.googleapis.com"
    port="5236"
    subscription-mode="accept_all"/>

  <int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="gcmOutboundAdapter"
    xmpp-connection="xmppConnection"
    channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"/>
```

`tracker.server.app.id` is a 12 digit number
and `tracker.auth.key` is like `AIzaSyBdfZ4oBaVuu07sjW5e9DnogeUF6NV****` (I put in the asterisks).

What am I missing?

Comment: Just in case: can you do that without Spring Integration? I mean the direct usage of the Smack lib

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639766/spring-integration-xmpp-and-google-cloud-messaging) and its answers.

Comment: @GaryRussell, your link and AniV's point to the same question but in different websites. That's a totally different question dealing with a totally different problem. I believe that and my question are the only ones in stackoverflow that have questions on spring-integration and gcm.

That question and a few examples in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/ were what I used to configure xmpp-connection. Looking at that question helped but the guy's not said how he configured his stuff.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I did what you said. I used the [code snippet in the android documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#implement). The connection is established and I can even send messages to the device. I did send a message from the device to the server but I don't know how to receive it yet. That's another problem.


Now knowing that the stack library worked by itself, does that help with solving my problem?

Comment: Just so we are clear, spring-integration uses the smack library too.

Comment: Why do you think that it is a different issue? As we see by that `GCM Cloud Connection Server` sample, they supply `GcmPacketExtension`. That is exactly we talked about. Spring Integration doesn't support any `PacketExtension`s yet. You have to add those options for the `ConnectionConfiguration` as well. Use `XmppConnectionFactoryBean` directly instead of `<int-xmpp:xmpp-connection>`

Answer (score 1):

I have configured the xmpp connection as a bean like this:

```
@Configuration
public class GcmXmppConnection {

@Value("${gcm.senderID}")
private String username;

@Value("${gcm.apiKey}")
private String password;

@Value("${gcm.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${gcm.port}")
private int port;

@Bean(name="gcmConnection")
public XmppConnectionFactoryBean xmppConnectionFactoryBean(){

    ConnectionConfiguration configuration = new    ConnectionConfiguration(host, port);
    configuration.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
    configuration.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
    configuration.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
    configuration.setSendPresence(false);
    configuration.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

//      configuration.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    XmppConnectionFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean = new XmppConnectionFactoryBean(configuration);

    connectionFactoryBean.setUser(username);
    connectionFactoryBean.setPassword(password);

    return connectionFactoryBean;
}
}
```

The configuration is autowired in the xml configuration like this:

```
<!-- Outbound messages to gcm -->
    <int:chain input-channel="androidNotificationOutputChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="androidMessageTransformer"></int:transformer>
    <int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter xmpp-connection="gcmConnection"/>
</int:chain>

<!-- Inbound messages from gcm -->
<int:channel id="gcmInboundNotificationChannel"/>
<int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter id="gcmInboundAdapter"
    channel="gcmInboundNotificationChannel" xmpp-connection="gcmConnection"
    extract-payload="true" auto-startup="true" />
```

The last piece is androidMessageTransformer, it's pretty simple, like the gcmXmppConnection bean it was coded along the example in google documentation.

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class AndroidMessageTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {

public final static String DESTINATION_HEADER_KEY="push.destinationID";

private final static String MESSAGE_ID_FORMAT = "%s-%s";

@Value("${gcm.senderID}")
private String senderId;

@Autowired
ObjectMapper om;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected Object doTransform(Message<?> msgIn) throws Exception {
    Map<String,String> data = (Map<String, String>) msgIn.getPayload();
    String registrationID = msgIn.getHeaders().get(DESTINATION_HEADER_KEY,String.class);
    Map<String, Object> gcmPayload = new HashMap<>();

    gcmPayload.put("to", registrationID);
    gcmPayload.put("message_id", String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, MESSAGE_ID_FORMAT, senderId, UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
    gcmPayload.put("data", data);

    String gcmJsonPayload = om.writeValueAsString(gcmPayload);

    org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message xmppMessage = new org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message();
    xmppMessage.addExtension(new GcmPacketExtension(gcmJsonPayload));

    return xmppMessage;
}
}
```

This works reliably for me, although I have mostly worked with the outbound direction, and never checked much about the inbound side.

Comment: It would be really awesome if you could edit your answer and share what `androidMessageTransformer` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `auto-startup="true"` in the `<int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter` tag. Refer to the following [answer](http://www.tagwith.com/question_473622_spring-integration-xmpp-and-google-cloud-messaging/) might work for you.

Comment: I think the default value for `auto-startup` is `true` but so to be sure I did what you said, compiled and deployed and it didn't change a thing. Still getting the same result.